# Converting German Letters to Uppercase won't work

Tags: c++, vector, count, find, countif

What is wrong with this code? It does not make them to uppercase, as I want to, if there is a letter in a string such as `å`, `ä` or `ö`. Is there something I'm missing?

Is there any way in C++ to make German letters to uppercase in some way with the library?

```
string makeUpperCase(string c)
{
    transform(c.begin(), c.end(), c.begin(), ::toupper);
    while(c.find("Ä") != string::npos)
    {
        c.replace(c.find("Ä"), 2, "ä");
    }
    while(c.find("Å") != string::npos)
    {
        c.replace(c.find("Å"), 2, "å");
    }
    while(c.find("Ö") != string::npos)
    {
        c.replace(c.find("Ö"), 2, "ö");
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Since when is `å` a German letter?

Comment: Note that [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) has undefined behavior for most negative values (even if most platforms can cope with most of them). In order to prevent the undefined behavior, the function argument of `toupper` should be cast to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for *uppercase* letters and replacing them with *lowercase* letters.

If you want to make the letters to uppercase, you have to do the opposite.

```cpp
string makeUpperCase(string c)
{
        transform(c.begin(), c.end(), c.begin(), ::toupper);
        while(c.find("ä") != string::npos)
        {
                c.replace(c.find("ä"), 2, "Ä");
        }
        while(c.find("å") != string::npos)
        {
                c.replace(c.find("å"), 2, "Å");
        }
        while(c.find("ö") != string::npos)
        {
                c.replace(c.find("ö"), 2, "Ö");
        }

        return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On many platforms, the function `toupper` can also deal with German characters. However, in the default `"C"` locale, it only considers the characters `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z` to be alphabetical letters. You will therefore have to change the locale to German, so that the function also considers German letters to be valid alphabetical letters. You can do this with the function [`std::setlocale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale).

Which locales are available and what their names are, is not specified by the ISO C standard. However, on Microsoft Windows using Microsoft Visual Studio, you can write

```
std::setlocale( LC_ALL, "de-DE" );
```

to set the locale to German.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <clocale>

int main( void )
{
    //define text string with German-specific characters
    std::string str{ "This is a test string with ä, ö and ü." };

    //set the locale to German
    std::setlocale( LC_ALL, "de-DE" );

    //convert string to upper-case
    std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper) );

    //output converted string
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

This program has the following output on that platform:

```
THIS IS A TEST STRING WITH Ä, Ö AND Ü.
```

As you can see, also the German letters were made upper-case.

For setting the locale to German on Linux, see [the Linux documentation for `setlocale`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html).

Comment: Hey Andreas! Thank you! I use this code on windows, and I use VS code, however it does not give the same output as yours!! May I ask what  IDE do you use?

Comment: @Justin: I am using [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) (which is a completely different product to [Microsoft Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), despite the very similar name). I have edited my answer, because it probably only works with the Microsoft compiler on Windows. Is my assumption correct that you are using a non-Microsoft compiler (even if your IDE is from Microsoft)? Did you check the return value of `setlocale`? Does it return `NULL`?

Comment: @Justin: If `std::setlocale` does return `NULL` (or `nullptr`) with you, then you will have to look at the platform-specific documentation of the run-time library that you are using, in order to find out which locales are accepted. You may want to try `"de_DE.UTF-8"`, assuming that your compiler is using UTF-8. Note that I am now using an underscore `_` instead of a hyphen `-` as the third character.